# CLLocationCoordinate2DMake behaviour

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, mkmapview

ok im trying to deal with something strange and i don't know if its just me

im trying to use

```
 CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(54.607313, -1.292585);
```

if i write it like this it works fine, but if i try to use

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng);
```

(lat and lng values passed from previous vc) i does not work. i can log out the numbers and they are the same.

society[1703:307] 1.052294
society[1703:307] 1.052294

am i doing something silly?

Comment: check in debugger (or log them) - probably lat and lng are indeed the same for some reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok , yes i was doing something stupid, and just to point it out remember when working with coords the "-" is a very important symbol

:O